# Javascript: Declare custom event with custom parameters

Tags: javascript

I'm coding a Javascript Web app and I want to send a custom event when a controller button is pressed. That event should have custom parameters: event.index, event.player2, and event.button. However, none of them are defined in the resulting event. This is what I tried so far:

I first declared the event as follows:

```
var testEvent = new Event('controllerPress', {
  index: 0,
  player2: false,
  button: 12
});
```

After that didn't work, I looked up some Q&As online (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613456)), and redeclared the event as such...

```
var testEvent = new Event('controllerPress', {
  detail: {
    index: 0,
    player2: false,
    button: 12
  }
});
```

...but to no avail. I looked again and changed the declaration to use `CustomEvent`...

```
var testEvent = new CustomEvent('controllerPress', {
  detail: {
    index: 0,
    player2: false,
    button: 12
  }
});
```

...but `testEvent.index` is still undefined. What am I missing?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of [“Create JavaScript custom event”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344625) because that asks how to create a custom event at all, but this asks how to add a custom property to that custom event.

Comment: You need to access it from the `detail` property of the event, eg inside event callback `eventVariable.detail.index`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create JavaScript custom event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344625/create-javascript-custom-event)

Comment: @GoodSamaritan No, because that asks how to create an event at all, while this asks how to add a custom property to that custom event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, **there is no way to do this.** The best workaround JS has to offer is this:

```
var event = new CustomEvent('PutYourEventNameHere', {
  detail: { // filled with sample values
    index: 0,
    player2: false,
    button: 1
  }
});
```

But this won't set the properties as you would expect.

```
event.index
>>> undefined
event.player2
>>> undefined
event.button
>>> undefined
```

All you can do with a CustomEvent is to **set the parameter `detail` instead**, resulting in this kind of behavior:

```
event.detail.index
>>> 0
event.detail.player2
>>> false
event.detail.button
>>> 1
```

Conclusion: If you're making a custom event, you can only define `detail`. But you can define `detail` as an `object` to add multiple custom properties. It's ugly, but that's what we have.