# Is there any reason not to define custom properties on an Event object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there any reason not to define custom properties on an Event object in JavaScript for the most part?

I am dispatching my own event on the window object and I want to add relevant properties to the event object.

Is it frowned upon to define custom properties on an Event object in JavaScript? A frown or grimace?

```
var infoEvent = new Event("info");
infoEvent.message = message;
infoEvent.referenceID = id;
window.dispatchEvent(infoEvent);
```

It is not guaranteed to have ES5 or ES6.

*Looks like an alternative was suggested in a comment to use a CustomEvent.*

Comment: Maybe look at the [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) api .

Comment: The only problem would be if you somehow overwrite a well defined property name and some script was also listening to this event and expecting this well defined property to be something else, but... is it really a problem?

Comment: Yes, you can assign custom properties to Objects.

Comment: I would say it's generally frowned upon to modify global objects. Instead, use custom objects/classes.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst `infoEvent` is not a global object, that's an Event **instance**. No other object will be modified.

Comment: I'm aware. I would say it's still frowned upon.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst If you found this code somewhere you would frown but would you change it?

Comment: @DylanLandry It looks like CustomEvents are for this purpose. Never heard of them until now. Maybe could you make that an answer? And reopen this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Declare custom event with custom properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58953249/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

No, you should never define custom properties on DOM objects. There are [many properties on the `Event` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), and even if you don't collide with any of them now there might be additional ones in the future. Notice there already is an [`MessageEvent` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent) and even a [`MediaKeyMessageEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaKeyMessageEvent) that does have a `.message` property.

The proper way to attach custom data to custom DOM events is [to use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23344625/1048572) the [`CustomEvent` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) and put the data on its [`.detail` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/detail) (which you can initialise from the constructor).